# FFMpeg autorotate video and image output

Tags: video, ffmpeg, nvidia, video-thumbnails, nvenc

I have a video which I'm trying to downscale to a video output, and also create a thumbnail image at every 2 seconds using a single FFMpeg command(hardware accelerated). Following is the command:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -hwaccel_output_format cuda -noautorotate  -i "inputVideo.mp4" -vf "scale_cuda=1280:720,hwdownload,format=nv12,setsar=1:1" -c:v h264_nvenc -profile:v main -level:v 4 -b:v 2500K "outputVideo.mp4" -vf "scale_cuda=160:90,hwdownload,format=nv12, fps=0.5,setsar=1:1" "thumbnailOutputs_%04d.jpg"
```

But the input video has a rotation parameter(180 degrees) in its metadata, and based on the [FFMpeg Documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Video-Options) the command automatically rotates the output since `-autorotate` is enabled by default. I don't want my outputs to be rotated.

> -autorotate Automatically rotate the video according to file metadata. Enabled by default, use -noautorotate to disable it.

I changed my command to add `-noautorotate`. It fixed the video output, but the image outputs are still getting rotated. I even tried separating the the command for images and using `-noautorotate` but still doesn't work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.